# Wiring ceiling light from switch that controls outlet

Tags: switch, receptacle, light-fixture

I am trying to add a ceiling light to a switch that currently controls a floor outlet (top plug only).  Coming into the light switch are a ground, a hot and a switched hot.  I have pulled an additional 12/2 wire from the ceiling light into the switch box and was wondering how I could wire it in to control both the outlet as it currently is, as well as the ceiling light.

The wire pulls into the attic are pretty difficult as there is 18" of insulation and plaster, so avoiding another pull to the outlet would be preferable, but I understand you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: Is there a neutral in the switch box (white wire, ground is green or bare)?  You need a neutral, ground, and switched hot for the new light.

Comment: @JPhi1618 bare ground, white wire and black wire.  When using voltage tester both white and black are "hot"

Comment: Are you willing to sacrifice the *switched-hot* receptacle?  (I would lol, I think they're stupid).  You would then need to walk over to that lamp to switch it on/off.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound like this will be possible. What you have now in the switch box is just a switch loop--hot in and hot out. There's no neutral return path, which would be required for your light.

If you were to connect your light to what's there it would probably work, but everything that gets plugged into the outlet thereafter would have its supply voltage reduced by the light bulb(s), *and* the current drawn by the outlet load would be pulled through the light bulb. The two loads would be in series. You can see how that's a problematic situation.

You'll need to pull a new home run, *or* you could possibly reconfigure the switched outlet to eliminate that function and provide an actual neutral at the switch. Update your question with information about the outlet box if you'd like help with that.

Comment: If I was to make the outlet always hot could I use the existing run from it to the switch as a power source for the light?

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting. See the linked duplicate for a clear explanation.

Comment: I'll give that a try tonight and mark your answer if that works correctly.  I did read the link you provided above as well before posting this, but was seeing if there might be a different way. thank you for your help everyone

Comment: @NickG, you're backed into a corner because you need a wire you don't have.  The options are to pull a new wire from the outlet box, or repurpose a wire you already have (and loose the ability to switch the outlet).

Comment: @JPhi1618 that sounds good, honestly I couldn't care less about the outlet being switched whatsoever, will just have to turn on a lamp by hand moving forward, the horror lol thank you

Comment: @NickG, horror indeed.  There are several smart switch solutions to that problem. No need to sully your hand on that lamp knob.  Feel free to post more questions if you run into issues!